# Dictionary like get() on pandas Series with index value like iloc

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have following pandas' Series:

```py
series=pd.Series(data=['A', 'B'], index=[2,3])
```

I can get the first value using `.iloc` as `series.iloc[0] #output: 'A'`

Or, I can just use the `get` method passing the actual index value like `series.get(2) #output: 'A'`

But is there any way to pass `iloc` like indexing to `get` method to get the first value in the series?

```py
>>> series.get(0,  '')
''     # Expected 'A', the first value for index 0
```

One way is to just reset the index and drop it then to call `get` method:

```py
>>> series.reset_index(drop=True).get(0,  '')
'A'
```

Is there any other function similar to `get` method (or a way to use `get`  method) that allows passing `iloc` like index, without the overhead of resetting the index?

**EDIT:** Please be noted that this series comes from dataframe masking so this series can be empty, that is why I intentionally added default value as empty string `''` for `get` method.

Comment: You need first value? Whats happen if empty `Series` ? Need `None` ?

Comment: yeah None is fine in case of empty series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `next` with `iter` if need first value also with empty Series:

```
next(iter(series), None)
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you have in mind or not really?

`series.get(series.index[0])`

Answer (score 1):

What about using `head` to get the first row and take the value from there?

```
series.head(1).item() # A
```